# Alembic migration server default value is recognized as null when trying to update a column

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

I am trying to do a migration to update the value of the column `has_bubble_in_countries` based on the `has_bubble_v1` s column value.

I created before the `upgrade()` the table:

```
subscription_old_table = sa.Table(
        'Subscription',
        sa.MetaData(),
        sa.Column('id', sa.Unicode(255), primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False),
        sa.Column('has_bubble_v1', sa.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False),
        sa.Column('has_bubble_in_countries', MutableList.as_mutable(ARRAY(sa.Enum(Country))), nullable=False, default=[], server_default='{}')
    )
```

And then the `upgrade()` method looks like:

```
def upgrade():

    connection = op.get_bind()

    for subscription in connection.execute(subscription_old_table.select()):
        if subscription.has_bubble_v1:
            connection.execute(
                subscription_old_table.update().where(
                    subscription_old_table.c.id == subscription.id
                ).values(
                    has_bubble_in_countries=subscription.has_bubble_in_countries.append(Country.NL),
                )
            )
    # Then drop the column after the data has been migrated
    op.drop_column('Subscription', 'has_bubble_v1')
```

All the rows in the database of `has_bubble_in_countries` column have this value {} when I check the database using pgadmin's interface.

When the `upgrade()` function gets to the update method it throws this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "has_bubble_in_countries" of relation "Subscription" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (keydsakwlkad, null, 2027-08-14 00:00:00+00,groot abonnement, big, {nl}, null, null, 2022-08-08 08:45:52.875931+00, 3482992, {}, f, null, null, null, t, 2011-05-23 08:55:20.538451+00, 2022-08-08 09:10:15.577283+00, ***null***).

[SQL: UPDATE "Subscription" SET has_bubble_in_countries=%(has_bubble_in_countries)s::country[] WHERE "Subscription".id = %(id_1)s]
[parameters: {'has_bubble_in_countries': None, 'id_1': '1pwohLmjftAZdIaJ'}]
```

The bolded value from the error is the value that is retrieved for the `has_bubble_in_countries` column even if it has a `server_default='{}'` and `nullable=False`.

Is there any possibility to add a configuration to alembic to recognize the server default s value when it is retrieved from the database? Or how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is actually that are you passing in the result of `.append()` which is None.  Unlike other languages where it is common to return the altered list, append changes the list in place.  I'm not sure that is a great idea for a core query result here but it seems to work.  Also as far as I know, if you pass in NULL it doesn't trigger the default.  The default is used when you pass in no value at all either when inserting or updating.

```py
with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():

    for subscription in session.execute(subscription_old_table.select()):
        if subscription.has_bubble_v1:
            # Append here.
            subscription.has_bubble_in_countries.append(Country.NL)
            # Then set values:
            session.execute(
                subscription_old_table.update().where(
                    subscription_old_table.c.id == subscription.id
                ).values(has_bubble_in_countries=subscription.has_bubble_in_countries,
                )
            )
```

Maybe cloning the list and then adding the element like this would be safer and clearer:

```py
has_bubble_in_countries=subscription.has_bubble_in_countries[:] + [Country.NL]
```